# Why is my RoR route using a different controller than the one I specify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my _navigation partial, I have the following link:

```
<%= link_to 'Manage email notifications',  {:controller => :users, :action => 'show',  :id => current_user.id}  %>
```

When the page is being rendered, I get an error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"high_voltage/users", :id=>1}
```

I'm very confused.  Why is it choosing the high_voltages/users controller?  I don't actually have a controller named that, the authorization package was put into our standard starter-kit rails app by another engineer, and I'm not really getting how to use it.

My routes file is like this:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
▫
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
    devise_scope :user do
        get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    end

    resources :users do
        post 'update'
    end

    root to: 'status#index'
end
```

Do I need to add a custom route to get where I want to go?  Or is there some other parameter to link_to I should be giving?

TIA

Comment: Why not use route helper instead? `user_path(current_user.id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory serves me right, that's an odd behaviour of that kind of helpers: they'll try to be smart and prepend the current controller, or it's parent module.

I remember a project where I solved it by prepending the controller name with a slash, to mark it as "root level":

```
<%= link_to 'Manage email notifications',  { controller: "/users", action: 'show',  id: current_user.id} %>
```

Of course, you could just use a path helper. In your case I guess it will be:

```
<%= link_to 'Manage email notifications', user_path(current_user) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer [path helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) to explicitly stating the controller.

In the root of your application, run `rake routes` to determine the name of your desired route.

In your case, this is probably `user`, which has the path `user_path`.

Adjust your code to look like this:

`<%= link_to 'Manage email notifications', user_path(current_user) %>`